# Solve exponential-polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials, logarithms, contest-math, exponentiation, roots

Solve the equation in $\mathbb{R}$

$$10^{-3}x^{\log_{10}x} + x(\log_{10}^2x - 2\log_{10} x) = x^2 + 3x$$

---

To be fair I wasn't able to make any progress. I tried using substitution for the logarithms, but it didn't help at all.

This is a contest problem, so there should be a nice solution.

Any help? Clue?

Comment: One solution is $x=1/10$.  Guess and check.

Comment: $x=1000$ also works.

Comment: @OpenSeason WolframAlpha gives another solution at $1000$ and it's the only integer solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $x > 0$.  Let $x = 10^y$.  Then we have $10^{-3}x^y + x(y^2 - 2y) = x^2 + 3x$.

$$\iff 10^{-3}x^{y-1} + (y-3)(y+1) = x$$
$$\iff 10^{y^2-y-3} + (y-3)(y+1) = 10^y$$
$$\iff \underbrace{10^y(10^{(y-3)(y+1)}-1)} + \underbrace{(y-3)(y+1)} = 0$$

Now note that if $(y-3)(y+1) > 0$, both terms on the left are positive, hence the equation cannot have a solution.  Similarly, if $(y-3)(y+1) < 0$, both terms are negative and again we cannot have a solution.  Hence the only solutions are when $(y-3)(y+1) = 0 \implies y \in \{-1, 3\} \implies x \in \{\frac1{10}, 1000\}$.

Comment: I've managed to solve this equation before, but anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: If the approach you had was different, you may want to add your solution to the question or as another answer, to aid others who may benefit from it.

Comment: My approach uses the same method that the $(y-3)(y+1)$ has to be equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

that is not a hard question !

you can assume :

$10^{a}=x$

then your problem turn out to be :

$x^2+(3-a^2+2a)x-\frac{x^a}{10^3}=0$$\Longrightarrow3-a^2+2a=0$$\Longrightarrow$$a\in[-1,3]$